# Term for someone who feel the need to learn

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there any specific term for someone who feel the need of constantly learning something new ? like a **learning disease**.

What should the appropriate term be?

Comment: Related: _What term means “one who enjoys learning”?_

Answer (score 3):

[Bookworm](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bookworm) may refer to excessive dedication to learning:

> - a person *excessively devoted to studying or reading* (Collins)

Comment: But you have to pick your dictionary carefully!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I know Collins is one of your favourites :)

Comment: It _is_ possible that the pejorative flavour is more prevalent in the UK than the US. My perception is that 'bookworm' is (1) a dated usage, (2) slightly hinting at eccentricity.

Comment: Not that dated, apparently: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bookworm%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbookworm%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbookworm%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbookworm%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I've checked the first pages of hits for the word: almost all seem to be names of products, often childrens books. This skews the recent data significantly (though doubtless conversational usage is influenced by such names).

Comment: Definitely think it answers the question, but it narrows the scope subtly to those who enjoy learning through books vs experience (& to be fair, probably what the OP meant)

Answer (score 1):

An ***intellectually curious*** person?

Answer (score 1):

The closest single definition to what you've outlined is a philomathic, from the Greek root φιλια (philia) meaning love and μαθανω (mathanó) meaning learn. It's an adjective and it means: relating to or enjoying the process of learning new facts and acquiring new knowledge. As in, "All he did was study and read all day. His friends thought he was crazy, but he was just philomathic".

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but I think *inquisitive* is not bad

> given to inquiry, research, or asking questions; **eager for knowledge**; intellectually curious: an inquisitive mind.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inquisitive)

Comment: I like inquisitive as it avoids academic overtones of some other possible answers